# Out-of-table column sorting with Glazed Lists and a JXTable

Tags: java, sorting, jtable, glazedlists, jxtable

I'm using Glazed Lists to sort and filter a JXTable.

How can I sort on out-of-table values? That is, I would like to be able to format column values in my own way, yet sort on raw values.

My current relevant code:

```
EventList<Foo> foos = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(new BasicEventList<Foo>());
foos.add(new Foo("bar", 5000000));

ObservableElementList.Connector<Foo> fooConnector = GlazedLists.beanConnector(Foo.class);
EventList<Foo> observedFoos = new ObservableElementList<Foo>(foos, fooConnector);

SortedList<Foo> sortedFoos = new SortedList<Foo>(observedFoos, null);

EventTableModel tableModel = new EventTableModel(sortedFoos, someTableFormat);
JXTable t = new JXTable(tableModel);

new TableComparatorChooser<Foo>(t, sortedFoos, false);
```

In this example, I would like to format the value in the second column as `5.0M` rather than `5000000`, but if I use this value in the list, it won't sort properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have to disable the JXTable Sorting, so it does not interfere with the GL sorting? Something like:

```
jxtable.setSortable(false);
jxtable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
jxtable.setRowSorter(null);
```

... and then install GlazedLists TableComparatorChooser on the table like:

```
TableComparatorChooser.install(jxtable, sortedFoos, TableComparatorChooser.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Or do you mean, you want to format 5000000 as 5.0M in the table, not in the List? Then you would only have to implement your TableFormat's

```
public Object getColumnValue(E yourObject, int column)
```

to return the 5.0M representation of 5000000.

... could well be, that I did not fully understand the problem and these answers are not helping ;-)

**EDIT: Runnable example...**

Look at the code in the main method - especially the code with the START-END comment.
I made my own very simple example, but you should understand, what I mean.

Oh... sorry for the naming of classes/variables/... ;-)

```
import ca.odell.glazedlists.BasicEventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.SortedList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.gui.TableFormat;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.EventTableModel;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.TableComparatorChooser;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;

public class Tester {

    private static class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {

        private final int number;
        private final String value;

        public MyObject(int number, String value) {
            this.number = number;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyObject t) {
            return value.compareTo(t.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static class MyTableFormat implements TableFormat<MyObject> {

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return "FormattedNumber";
                case 1:
                    return "String";
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getColumnValue(MyObject e, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return getNumberString(e.getNumber());
                case 1:
                    return e.getValue();
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }

        private Object getNumberString(int number) {
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    return "One";
                case 2:
                    return "Two";
                case 3:
                    return "Three";
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject t, MyObject t1) {
            return Integer.valueOf(t.getNumber()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(t1.getNumber()));
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventList<MyObject> list = new BasicEventList<MyObject>();
        list.add(new MyObject(1, "A"));
        list.add(new MyObject(2, "B"));
        list.add(new MyObject(3, "C"));

        SortedList<MyObject> sortedList = new SortedList<MyObject>(list);

        EventTableModel<MyObject> tableModel = new EventTableModel<MyObject>(sortedList, new MyTableFormat());
        JXTable jxtable = new JXTable(tableModel);

        /** 
         * START
         * - Deactivate JXTables build-in sorting
         * - Install GlazedLists sorting
         * - Set the comparator for the "string number" column
         */

        // deactivate sorting of JXTable
        jxtable.setSortable(false);
        jxtable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
        jxtable.setRowSorter(null);

        // enable GlazedLists sorting
        TableComparatorChooser<MyObject> tcc = TableComparatorChooser.install(jxtable, sortedList, TableComparatorChooser.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        // set the comparator for your "string number" column
        List<Comparator> comparators = tcc.getComparatorsForColumn(0);
        comparators.clear();
        comparators.add(new MyComparator());

        /**
         * END
         */

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Tester");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jxtable));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Kai. It is the second option that I am trying to achieve. I have tried `getColumnValue(Object baseObject, int column)` to format the value as 5.0M, but then it won't sort properly, since I'm formatting 5.0M as a string. So it seems to sort based on `getColumnValue(Object baseObject, int column)` rather than the initial list.

Comment: Did you try to switch of the sorting mechanism of the JXTable and then install the sorting mechanism of Glazed lists (TableComparatorChooser)? It could be, that on clicking the table header, you start the JXTable sorting instead of the GlazedLists sorting...

Comment: Thanks very much Kai for this very complete answer. The problem was that I wasn't calling `comparators.clear()` before adding my comparator. It wasn't possible to determine this from my original question, so well done :-) Hopefully others will find your answer in the future. Thanks again.